# Can ArcGis use imagery from Google or Bing in order to compute Service Areas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, bing-maps, service-area

I am trying to make service areas and I am wondering if I can use one of the open source data for it, not as a basemap, but if the software can take the real-time information from these maps, such as oneway restrictions, speed limits and so on.

When working with normal layer for roads I don't have all this data and also it is not provided the history data so that I can use different time when computing the service areas.

Comment: What area of the world do you need to do this for?

Comment: I will do it from the most important cities of Denmark.

Comment: You will not need "imagery" from Google or Bing, what you need is the road network in order to calculate service areas based on either network length or network time.  I know that MapQuest for Developers offers the use of their network data for developers with some functionality.  You might find some useful information at this link:  https://developer.mapquest.com/products/data-manager/